# getting an item id from a database

Tags: android, sqlite

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {

        etupdateName = findViewById(R.id.edit_item);

        String name =  (aitems.get(0).getItemName());
        etupdateName.setText(name);


    }
```

I want to display the item name in the EditText by Click the listView item. I almost there , i can only display the item name where the index = 0, which is   String name =  (aitems.get(0).getItemName());
Example, I click whatever in the list, it always display the first item name which the index=0.

i want to get whatever the item id is so i can display the item name whatever the id is.
Example, I click the item where id=2 in the listview, it will display the item name where item id = 2. 
i click the item where id =3 in the listview, it will display the item name where the item id =3.

Comment: Few things to consider. 
1 - You should initialize you Edit Text outside click event.
2 -  Please visit the link to understand click listener.(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) 
3 -  With  index 0 it will always return the name at index 0. Use position variable it should be (aitems.get(position).getItemName());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need get the text from each position Try this...

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{

    etupdateName = findViewById(R.id.edit_item);

    String name =  (aitems.get(position).getItemName());
    etupdateName.setText(name);


}
```